# Better (shorter) solution for this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following scripts which add a class to an element on hover.

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to JS so as you can see from the code below I have used the same script for each individual ID. I am sure there must be a way to have on script that does the same job.

The reason I have written a separate script for each is because my original script would add the ".slidein" class to each "#project-box" rather than just the one that was hovered over.

**The Script's**

```
<script>

$("#project-box-one")
.mouseenter(function(){
$(".project-overlay-one").addClass("slidein");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
$(".project-overlay-one").removeClass("slidein");
});


$("#project-box-two")
.mouseenter(function(){
$(".project-overlay-two").addClass("slidein");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
$(".project-overlay-two").removeClass("slidein");
});


$("#project-box-three")
.mouseenter(function(){
$(".project-overlay-three").addClass("slidein");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
$(".project-overlay-three").removeClass("slidein");
});

</script>
```

**An example of the HTML for a "project-box"**

```
<div id="project-box-one">
    <div class="project-overlay-one">
          <h1>Chy an Albany Hotel</h1>
          <a href="#" class="project-link">view project</a>
    </div>
         <a href="#">
         <img src="img/portfolio/thumbs/chy-an-albany.jpg" width="300" height="310">
         </a>
</div>
```

**And the CSS"**

```
.project-box {
      width: 33.3333%;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 0.9375em;
      padding-right: 0.9375em;
      float: left;
      height: 310px;
      overflow: hidden;
 }

 #project-box-one, #project-box-two, #project-box-three {
      width: 33.3333%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.9375em;
  padding-right: 0.9375em;
  float: left;
  height: 310px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  .project-overlay.slidein, 
  .project-overlay-one.slidein, 
  .project-overlay-two.slidein, 
  .project-overlay-three.slidein {
      transition: 600ms ease-in;
  top: -340px;
   }
```

Comment: Use custom `data-` attributes

Comment: If your code is working and you're looking for feedback on making it "better", it seems that [codereview.se] would be the right place to ask.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because properly belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of `IDs`, use `classes`, if they're all the same, there's no point giving them `IDs` such as one, two etc.

Comment: Sorry for the "off-topic" to be honest I did not know codereview existed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't *really* need ids here :

- use a `.project-box` class instead of `#project-box-xxx` ids
- use a `.project-overlay` class instead of `#project-overlay-xxx` ids
- generalize your JS/CSS using these classes instead of multiple ids
- (bonus) use jQuery [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function instead of `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

```
<script>
/* Thanks to cookie_monster for the toggleClass shortcut */
$('.project-box')               // for each .project-box
  .hover(                       // on each mouseenter AND mouseleave event
    function(e){                // run this anonymous function
      $(this).toggleClass(      // get hovered element, and add/remove a class
        'slidein',              // this class is .slidein
        e.type === "mouseenter" // if event type is mouseenter we add the class, else, we remove it
      ); 
    }
  );    
</script>
```

```
<div class="project-box">
    <div class="project-overlay">
          <h1>Chy an Albany Hotel</h1>
          <a href="#" class="project-link">view project</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
         <img src="img/portfolio/thumbs/chy-an-albany.jpg" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
</div>
```

```
.project-box {
      width: 33.3333%;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 0.9375em;
      padding-right: 0.9375em;
      float: left;
      height: 310px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.project-overlay.slidein {
    transition: 600ms ease-in;
    top: -340px;
}
```

Comment: +1 You could even reduce it down to a single function if you wanted to: `function(e){ $(this).find('.project-overlay').toggleClass('slidein', e.type === "mouseenter"); }`

Comment: @cookiemonster Hey ! Great tip, I never used this second parameter for `toggleClass()`.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you so much. Love the "bonus" .hover as well!

Comment: And even better @cookiemonster thanks!

Comment: @zessx I don't suppose a breakdown of the script would be possible? Just so I can learn the technique rather than just copying and pasting without fully understanding?

Comment: @JamesHusband Of course you can, this edit should be enough. Take the time to look for `hover()` and `toggleClass` jQuery doc.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<!-- add class="project-box" to each div -->
<div id="project-box-one" class="project-box">
    <div class="project-overlay-one">
        <h1>Chy an Albany Hotel</h1>
        <a href="#" class="project-link">view project</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbs/chy-an-albany.jpg" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// use the class selector, and add and remove the classes on the specific instance of that class
$(".project-box").mouseenter(function(){
    // $(this).addClass("slidein");
    // just noticed this line is wrong, an alternative to @zessx's would be the following:
    $(this).children('.project-overlay').addClass('slidein');
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    // $(this).removeClass("slidein");
    // just noticed this line is wrong, an alternative to @zessx's would be the following:
    $(this).children('.project-overlay').removeClass('slidein');
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* #project-box-one, #project-box-two, #project-box-three { */
.project-box {
```

**TLDR:** use `class`es instead of `id`'s

Comment: You should be adding a class to `project-overlay` inside the clicked item

Comment: yeah, just noticed that, changed the answer